# how to get attribute value using selenium and css

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-rc

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<a href="/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=1"> 2 </a>
```

I would like to get what is contained in href, ie, I was looking for a command which would give me "/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=1" value for href.

Could someone please help me with the respective command and css locator in selenium, for the above query?

if I have something like:

```html
<a href="/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=1"> 2 </a> 
<a href="/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=2"> 3 </a>
```

Out of these two if I was to get the attribute value for href whose text conatins '2', then how would my css locator synatx look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your HTML consists solely of that one `<a>` tag, then this should do it:

```java
String href = selenium.getAttribute("css=a@href");
```

You use the [`DefaultSelenium#getAttribute()` method](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) and pass in a CSS locator, an `@` symbol, and the name of the attribute you want to fetch. In this case, you select the `a` and get its `@href`.

In response to your comment/edit:

1. The part after `@` tells Selenium that that part is the name of the attribute.
2. You should place `:contains('2')` before `@href` because it's part of the locator, not the attribute. So, like this:

   ```java
   selenium.getAttribute("css=a:contains('2')@href");
   ```

Comment: thanks BoltClock, this was great help. I just have a couple of questions relatd to this:
1. What does @ mean?
2. if I have something like:
<a href="/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=1"> 2 </a>
<a href="/search/?p=2&q=move&mt=2"> 3 </a>
Out of these two if I was to get the attribute value for href whose text conatins '2', then how would my css locator synatx look like?
I tried  
selenium.getattribute("css=div#paginationContainer a@href:contains('2')")
but this gives the following error: Could not find element attribute: css=div#paginationContainer a@href:contains('2')

thanks in advanvce

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it was very helpful, it worked. I have one more query in the same regard actually. Is there a way to check whether the attribute href is present in a particular HTML tag using css and selenium. So, for example, in the above case, if I want to check if the HTML tag which conatins text '2', contains href attribute or not? Is that possible and how? Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Try `selenium.isElementPresent("css=a[href]:contains('2')")`

Comment: excellent, it all worked great. One last question. This will hopefully be the last. Learnt a lot today. OK, so i need to check if some text on the page is bold or not. How would i do that?

Comment: Not sure about that, sorry. (I know it's your last question.)

Comment: excellent, it all worked great. One last question. This will hopefully be the last. Learnt a lot today. OK, so i need to check if some text on the page is bold or not. How would i do that?
I thought of the follwoing things but could not find a way to implemement these:
1. usually <div><b>1</b>.....</div> is in bold, so is there a way to check if inside my 'div', if the text contains the tag <b> or not. But i dont know how to do this in selenium?
2. Sometimes font-weight:bold is used but this is not a part of the tag itself, so i am not sure if this would work?
could you please help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Changing css=a@href to href should do the trick. Let me if this did not work.

```
    List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.className("c"));
        for(WebElement e : ele)
        {
           String doctorname = e.getText();
           String linkValue = e.getAttribute("href");
        }
```