# How can I get the href of elements found by partial link text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium and the Chrome Driver I do:

`links = browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('##')` matches about 160 links.

If I try,

```
for link in links:
    print link.text
```

with it I get the text of all the links:

```
##1
##2
...
##160
```

The links are like this:

```
<a href="1.html">##1</a>
<a href="2.html">##2</a>
...
<a href="160.html">##160</a>
```

How can I get the `href` attribute of all the links found?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Call [`get_attribute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) on each of the links you have found:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('##')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: I found that I needed to use: `link._element.get_attribute("href")`. (that was when making the request with: `browser.find_by_tag('a')`

Answer (score 2):

[An existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201409/) to a similar question seems like it might apply:

Assume

> your HTML consists solely of that one  tag, then this should do it:

```
String href = selenium.getAttribute("css=a@href");
```

> You use the `DefaultSelenium#getAttribute()` method  and pass in a CSS locator, an `@` symbol, and the name of the attribute you want to fetch. In this case, you select the `a` and get its `@href`.

So if the link contains "..blablabla..."  text then you can find it in that way:

```
selenium.getAttribute("css=a:contains('..blablabla...')@href");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have more than on link and your code is probably in Java, for now I cannot adapt this to my situation